# Bool function in c

Tags: c, boolean

```
bool checkPalindrome(char * inputString) {

    int i,j,l;
    char b[50];

    l=strlen(inputString);

    for(i=0;i<l-1;i++)
    {
        b[i]=inputString[l];

    }
    printf("l is %d",l);
    if(l==1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if((strcmp(inputString,b))==0)

            {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

What is wrong in this function?
it always give answer of else part

Comment: forgetting to nul terminate `b`

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: The loop is copying the null byte at the end of `inputString` into every element of `b`.

Comment: Some things never change -- like `l` in `inputString[l]`

Comment: It's doing exactly what you're **telling** it to do, just not what you're **thinking** it to do. If you don't tell us what do you want it to do (expected behavior) we can't help. (edit: ok, `checkPalindrome`, but your code isn't that self-explanatory)

Comment: @user202729.: well said.

Comment: Root cause: `for(i=0;i<l-1;i++){b[i]=inputString[l];}`

Comment: that is why it is recommended to have reasonable variable names instead of `i` and `l`

Comment: For the future, please turn on compiler warning. There's at least one place where an integer is truncated and which should give a warning.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre actually `b` is filled with null terminators

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Which is useless unless the OP is good enough to know how to read warning messages (or just have some research ability).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this loop:

```
for(i=0;i<l-1;i++)
{
    b[i]=inputString[l];

}
```

is supposed to be making `b` a reverse of `inputString`. But `inputString[l]` is the null byte at the end of the string, so it's just repeatedly copying that into the first `l-1` characters of `b`. It should be:

```
for(i=0;i<l;i++)
{
    b[i]=inputString[l-i-1];

}
```

And after that you need to add a null terminator to `b`:

```
b[i] = '\0';
```

You shouldn't use `l-1` as the limit of the loop, because then you won't copy the last character of the input string.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple mistakes in your code.

Try the following:

```
bool checkPalindrome(char * inputString) {

int i,j,l;
char b[50];

l=strlen(inputString);

for(i=0;i<l;i++)
{
    b[i]=inputString[l-i-1];

}
b[i] = '\0';
printf("%s\n",inputString);
printf("%s\n",b);
if(l==1)
{
    return true;
}
else if((strcmp(inputString,b))==0)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

}

Problems in your code:
1. String must be terminated by '\0'
2. Problem in copying string

Comment: it worked. thank you